# have trouble with markdown-preview.nvim in vim9

Tags: vim, markdown, i3

My desktop environment is i3 mainly with zsh ,chromium and vim9 where I have successfully installed markdown-preview.nvim pluggin. When a .md file is opened with vim,the plugin is auto-loaded ,but doesn't open chromium browser to preview and shows me the fault message below,literal meaning the file has "unterminated quoted string" syntax error which is not that thing in fact,or do I lose the true meaning of that message?

The whole message is "/home/XXX/.vim/plugged/markdown-preview.nvim/app/bin/markdown-preview-linux: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string"

By the way,paste my neofetch record here:
[my-neofetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL49c.png)

First I read the plugin src files and README file but had no clues,the I wrote a markdown file as simple as possible,then opened it with vim and the error was still there.I also googled and there's few pages and blogs exactly talk about the issue.So please help me make the Markdown-Preview.nvim plugin work in vim9 of i3 desktop.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble making markdown-preview working with Vim.
Here is a messages from people running different OSes [When I use :MarkdownPreview I have an error:](https://github.com/iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim/issues/476)

The solution found was to switch to the commit: `e5bfe9b`

You can either perform in the markdown-preview folder:

```
git checkout e5bfe9b
```

Or uninstall the plugin and install it with the following `Plug` instructions:

```
Plug 'iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim', { 'do': { -> mkdp#util#install() }, 'for': ['markdown', 'vim-plug'], 'commit': 'e5bfe9b'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind guidance.I am sorry for not trying hard to search and read the similar Q&A.This roll back method do gets rid of the error message but still doesn't work,even doesn't call chromium preview page.Maybe My debian lost yarn or the arch is i686?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I can't unfortunately reproduce your problem.

Comment: Maybe the laptop is too old,I don't have nodejs and yarn in it(yet don't want to),and finally with rust environment the vim-markdown-composer works.

Comment: You need indeed node.js for making it working.